# I want to create a login window using tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

can you compare entry field text to the username and password you want and put it in if-else statements to do different functions on clicking the button?
I can't do it using .get() function IDK why it isn't working or something is wrong with my code.

```
from tkinter import*
root =Tk()
header=Label(root ,text='Welcome to pokedex')
header.pack()
usernameLabel=Label(root,text="Username")
usernameLabel.pack()
a=""
b=""
usernameEntry=Entry(root,width=50)
usernameEntry.pack()
def usernameentry():
  a=usernameEntry.get()
b_1=Button(root,text="_/",command=usernameentry)
b_1.pack()
passwordLabel=Label(root,text="Password")
passwordLabel.pack()
passwordEntry=Entry(root,width=50)
passwordEntry.pack()
def passwordentry():
    b=passwordEntry.get()
b_2=Button(root,text="_/",command=passwordentry)
b_2.pack()
    
def correctpass():
    correctpassLabel=Label(root,text="Welcome to pokedex")
    correctpassLabel.pack()
def wrongpass():
    wrongpassLabel=Label(root,text="Sorry wrong username or password")
    wrongpassLabel.pack()
if a=="Malhar"and b=="123" :
    loginButton=Button(root,text="Login",command=correctpass)
    loginButton.pack()
else:
    loginButton=Button(root,text="Login",command=wrongpass)
    loginButton.pack()
    
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What do you expect to get from the two lines: `a=usernameEntry.get()` and `b=passwordEntry.get()`? You should get empty strings as there is nothing entered when the two lines are executed.

Comment: ya i  did that i have edited my code still the same prob..i checked in variable explorer .get() doesnt seem to store the value in empty string idk why

Comment: What do you expect `a` and `b` are when the line `if a=="..." and b="..."` is executed?  They are empty strings as well.  For better debugging, you should print the content of variables before the suspect statement.  Actually you better learn what is *event driven programming* first.

Comment: if u want, ill make the changes to ur code and post it as an asnwer, such that itll work

Comment: @CoolCloud yes pls make the changes

Comment: first: you should format your code - ie. put all functions before `root = Tk()` and add some empty lines to make it more readable. Second: you have to check `a` and `b` in function executed by button. because `GUI` doesn;t work like `input` and `Entry` doesn't wait for your text and all code after `Entry` is executed before you even see window with widgets. And you should check values in function assigned to button - so it will be check after you put text in Entry and press button.

Comment: BTW: [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: if iniside function you want to assing `a = ...` to exernal variable then you have to use `global a` inside function. If you don't use `global` then it will create local variable `a` and it will not change external `a`

Comment: thanks @furas i was curious abt global i just didn't know what it was...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You do not need that number of functions. only one is enough.
here is the code you can use. consider in mind I have changed variables. `user` is `a` and `pass_` is `b` for your code:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
header = Label(root ,text='Welcome to pokedex')
header.pack()
usernameLabel = Label(root,text="Username")
usernameLabel.pack()
usernameEntry = Entry(root,width=50)
usernameEntry.pack()
passwordLabel = Label(root,text="Password")
passwordLabel.pack()
passwordEntry = Entry(root,width=50)
passwordEntry.pack()

def login():
    user = usernameEntry.get()
    pass_ = passwordEntry.get()
    if user == 'Mahlar' and pass_ == '123':
        passLabel=Label(root,text="Welcome to pokedex")
    else:
        passLabel=Label(root,text="Sorry wrong username or password")
    passLabel.pack()

loginButton=Button(root,text="Login",command=login)
loginButton.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: @MalharGharat so glad to hear that.

Comment: @FarZad what is the difference bw this and the last answer?

Comment: @CoolCloud I just gave him a simple way to change his own code. seems you have added some lateral parts to run the program in a probable better way like `messagebox`. our answers were not sent with a big time difference. so please do not comment and talk like this :)

Comment: i did not mean it any bad way, i dint find much of a difference here, so i wanted to ask, why there is an answer such as, when already a very similar answer is answerd. In SO, this could even be like spamming answers. Just wanted to educate and point it out to u

Answer (score 1):

Does this help you, understand better? I have imported `messagebox` from tkinter that helps you, show a message box, for errors and all.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox


root = Tk()

def login():
    if usernameEntry.get() == "Malhar" and passwordEntry.get() == "123":
        messagebox.showinfo('Successfull','Login successfull')
    else:
        messagebox.showerror('Invalid','Invalid username or password')

header = Label(root, text='Welcome to pokedex')
header.pack()

usernameLabel = Label(root, text="Username")
usernameLabel.pack()

usernameEntry = Entry(root, width=50)
usernameEntry.pack()

passwordLabel = Label(root, text="Password")
passwordLabel.pack()

passwordEntry = Entry(root, width=50)
passwordEntry.pack()


b_2 = Button(root, text="Login",command=login)
b_2.pack(pady=10)


root.mainloop()
```

Plus, I also formatted your code according to pep8 :D
. Let me know, if any doubts

Cheers